# .NET DB2 driver options

Tags: c#, .net-core, db2, ibm-midrange

On NuGet, I see these DB2 packages:

- `IBM.Data.DB2`
- `IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries`
- `IBM.Data.DB2.Core`

Questions:

1. What is the difference between `IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries` and `IBM.Data.DB2`?
2. As I understand it, `IBM.Data.DB2` and `IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries` are not compatible with .NET Core.  Is that correct?
3. I assume `IBM.Data.DB2.Core` is the .NET Core equivalent of either `IBM.Data.DB2` or `IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries`.  Is that correct?  Which is it?
4. Does `IBM.Data.DB2.Core` lack any of key features of its predecessors?

At my company, we have an IBM i system, and we've used `IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries` successfully to date.  I want to use ASP.NET Core for a project, but I want to make sure `IBM.Data.DB2.Core` will not be a deal-breaker for some reason (assuming I can even get it working without throwing cryptic exceptions, but that's another discussion...).  The server will be running Windows Server 2019.  I know ODBC is also an option, but I've been told it lacks both features and performance compared to these DB2-specific drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have all answers but some.

1. IBM.Data.DB2 is used for the Informix database. But it seems to be no official package.
2. Yes. ADO.NET is Windows only.
3. It is for both of them. The IBM Data Server Drivers support both.
4. That depends on the product version and edition you bought.

I suggest you create a small test project with some of your scenarios before you start migrating your application. A starting point might be [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.install.doc/doc/r0054687.html).

Comment: Thanks!  I am new to IBM's ecosystem.  When you say it depends on the version/edition, you are talking about the version/edition of what?  IBM Data Server Drivers?  That's a paid product?

Comment: IBM Data server is a paid product. Maybe there is an alternative or a certain edition is included in the IBM i license. You should ask your IBM i admins. They can contact IBM about the pricing and alternatives. Unfortunately my customers run old versions of OS400 and for those there is only full framework support.